# Turn off the [heat]!

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

The tag [heat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heat) is currently being regularly misapplied, and therefore it is a good candidate for burnination. This tag has 251 questions at present.

Looking at the criteria for burnination:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

There is usage guidance for it:

> Heat is a harvesting tool that creates .wxs files that can be used to create an installer.

There are definitely relevant usages of it; of the 251 questions, 161 of them are tagged both [`wix` and `heat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix+heat) and relate to WiX's [Heat](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html) tool.

It is not unambiguous, though as the remaining questions seem to split into several categories:

- [Many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstack+heat) for Openstack [Heat](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Heat) which should have been tagged with the existing tag [openstack-heat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstack-heat)
- Many for [heatmaps](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/heatmap), which should have been tagged with the existing tag [heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heatmap), such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367651/baseball-heap-maps-in-r), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211566/r-color-map-with-wide-file), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49827096/generating-a-plotly-heat-map-from-a-pandas-pivot-table)
- Physical [heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat) - such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63491675/how-can-i-use-a-car-battery-inside-a-car-as-a-power-source-for-example-a-mini-re), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078862/how-can-i-turn-off-a-liquid-valve-when-a-flame-goes-out), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729882/how-can-i-find-the-temperature-distribution-over-the-plate-by-moving-laser-heat), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120317/why-does-the-temperature-t-not-change-when-i-change-total-time-t-for-2d-tran), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460719/cpu-overheat-using-handbrakecli) - quite a few off-topic, as you can see.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes, but the multiple meanings leads to this confusion

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

It probably does help identify WiX-Heat questions, but the mis-tagging will affect the discovery of questions that should have been otherwise-tagged.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

The tag guidance is clear, but the usage does not follow the guidance.

My suggestion:

- A brief community effort to correctly tag the Openstack and heatmap questions to [openstack-heat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstack-heat) and [heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heatmap).
- The thermal heat questions that aren't off-topic might be able to be retagged to [temperature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temperature), but an alternative would be to create [thermal-heat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thermal-heat) (perhaps as a synonym of temperature as there will be very few of them and temperature already has 486 questions).
- Finally, rename [heat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heat) to [wix-heat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix-heat) (unless there are better suggestions) to reduce the chances of it being misused in the future.

Comment: Trying to earn the name Trogdor, are you? ;-)

Comment: lol tag for overheating stuff

Comment: I'm not sure we need [temperature] or [thermal-heat] at all, in most cases thermal heat questions that aren't off-topic can have [heat] removed just like that without having it replaced with anything else. For example, if we take the two thermal heat questions you linked to that aren't off-topic, if it's a programming question about a program to calculate heat like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57120317/4284627), it doesn't need a heat-related tag at all, and if it's about CPU overheating like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60460719/4284627), I think the [cpu] tag is enough.

Comment: even if we don't to the rest of the above (which we should, IMO), creating `wix-heat` as a synonym of `heat` seems valuable as a discoverability change.

Comment: From [WiX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX), there is more trouble: *Candle* ("Windows Installer XML ***Compiler***"), *Light* ("Windows Installer XML ***Linker***"), and *Burn* (that creates "bundle" ***installers***). And *Lit*, *Dark*, and *Pyro*.

Comment: @DonaldDuck why should a programmer care that your system has a poor cooling solution?

Answer (score 7):

This is a common problem for tags for tools/libraries/concepts that has a name that is a common word. The solution is to create compound tags instead. In this case, the tag [wix-heat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix-heat).

Burninating this tag is a good idea.